# What do CR_DET#_LED and HD_LED mean?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, led

I was looking at a  [AMPKB-CT (Azure) motherboard](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03724033). There were two LEDs: CR_DET#_LED, and HD_LED. I am guessing the HD_LED is for the hard drive. It was off, but I could hear the hard drive spinning. The CR_DET#_LED was blinking slow and steady. What does it mean if they are on, off, or blinking?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the make and model of your motherboard. With this information we *might* be able to answer your question.

Comment: Are you asking what *both* of these LEDs do, or are you satisfied with your assumption that the HD LED is for the hard drive? Your question is ambiguous on that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CR_DET LED is related to the SD card reader that's built into the motherboard. The slot is immediately adjacent to the LED.

Here's the photo of the mobo (copied from the OP's link, and annotated by me):

[image]

These two LEDs are midway along the right-hand edge of the mobo (as seen in the photo). This is a SFF board. Given what else is along that edge, this edge of the mobo obviously presents user-accessible LEDs, ports, etc., on the side or front of the PC - and these are obviously user-visible LEDs, not internal diagnostics.

The CR_DET LED is just "above" (in the photo) the SD card reader slot, which is the big grey square with a bunch of parallel gold lines (contacts) on it. The card reader slot is even labeled "CARD_READER" on the mobo. (I've circled the legends HD#_LED, CR_DET#_LED, and CARD_READER in red. They are fairly legible if you enlarge the photo.)

Hence, in this case, CR = "card reader" and CR_DET likely means "card reader detect".

As further evidence, if we go to the spec sheet linked by the OP and expand the "I/O ports" section, we find a photo of "Side I/O ports". One of these is labeled "6-in-1 memory card reader". The callout for this encompasses both the slot and the LED that's next to it:

[image]

I have no idea why the LED would be constantly blinking unless there's a card in the reader and the card is being accessed. Usually no card = no LED, card present but not accessed = steady LED, card being accessed = blinking LED. But whatever it means, the LED is clearly related to the card reader.

I concur with Austin re the HD LED.

Comment: Very good detective work, probably this explanation is as valid as my answer. My problem with it is that it's found a lot in service manuals for TVs that don't have an SD card reader. This indication might of course pertain to more than one signal, maybe the "C" only means carry-signal.

Comment: I'm not saying it can't be something else in other contexts. Lots of different things could be abbreviated "CR". But in this case I see no reason why a SFF mobo for an all-in-one PC would put a detection LED for a component video signal where the user can see it. It's not as if the board has video inputs of any sort, and it doesn't support component output.

Comment: My current guess in my answer is  "CR_DET"="Carry-signal Receive DETection", which maybe would make sense in a video receiver circuit.

Comment: Where did you get "Carry-signal"? Just curious.

Comment: In one of the sources, but I can't find it again.

Answer (score 1):

The CR_DET#_LED I'm not sure about.  If the system was in a sleep state, this may have been the power LED, albeit with an odd name.  On most computers, a blinking power LED indicates that the system is in a sleep state (or transitioning into or out of one).

The HD_LED is probably for the hard drive.  On consumer systems, hard drive LED's usually show access to the hard drive, not the drive's power state.  So, it's pretty normal there for the LED to be unlit but the drive to be spinning.  Some server chassis have an LED for each hard drive, and these will generally indicate that the drive is powered on instead of indicating if it's in use (the really nice ones have two LED's for each drive, one that shows it's powered on, and one that show's when it's being accessed).

Answer (score 0):

My researches among several non-English manuals have brought me to the conclusion
that this has something to do with the video display, probably the VGA.

My current guess is that this refers to one of the components of a
video signal. Maybe "CR_DET" means "Carry-signal Receive DETection",
which makes sense when repairing a TV circuit.

Here is one excerpt from some of the manuals, all pertaining to TV repair:

[image]

More info from 
SONY LCD TV Service Manual for GN1T Chassis repair :

[image]

Comment: I highly doubt that "carriage return" is the correct interpretation, but I agree that this table is useful. Note that in the left column "CR" is styled "Cr" and it is an alternative to "Pr", in combination with "Y", referring to component video. This is referring to YPbPr or YCbCr - they're the same thing, a type of component video. But, why would you have a _slowly-blinking_ LED for that? I would think it would be constant. Incidentially the "#" in a signal name simply indicates an "active-low" signal: a low voltage denotes logic true. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#Technical_details

Comment: @JamieHanrahan: I changed this to column return, but I'm reasonably sure that this is part of a video circuit. I added a repair-man manual mentioning this.

Comment: I believe I  found some similar manuals :) Sorry but "column return" would make no sense because pixels come in by the row. Your first table still clearly associates CR_DET with the Cr in YCbCr. So does the flowchart, as VIDEO_DET refers to the Y.  (And of course component has no pixels at all...) Also, the end-of-row signal  in component video would not be called a "return" but rather a horizontal sync signal.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan: You are right, I think this is simply the detection of a video signal. The slow blink might denote some infrequent change on the line.

Comment: I've changed my mind. (I took the radical step of looking closely at the mobo photo in the OP's link. :) )